Microsoft MPI github project does not open in Visual Studio 2022
(Running: Windows 10, Visual Studio 2022)  I'm trying to build a project that uses the mpi.h #include file.  This set of libraries is not on my system.  I followed the link to the Microsoft MPI project on github (here's the link).  There is a Visual Studio project in the 'src' folder of that repository.  But when I try to open it in Visual Studio, I get a series of errors that say:
<path>\src\mpi\msmpi\dll\msmpi.vcxproj : error  : The function "GetType" on type "System.String" is not available for execution as an MSBuild property function.  <path>\.build\CBT\build.props
When I search that error, I get a link to another Microsoft page that indicates GetType is unpredictable.  However, the only recommended action is to "replace any calls to GetType() with alternative MSBuild logic", which is not exactly a comprehensive solution.
Can anyone suggest how to integrate the MPI libraries onto my system such that the mpi.h #include file is properly referenced by any Visual Studio 2022 project that might use it?
<Here's a summary of what I tried and what I expected>:
I used git clone to download the Microsoft MPI project to my PC.  I opened Visual Studio 2022 and tried to open the MPI project named <Project_Location>\src\msmpi.sln
I expected that the project would open and I would be able to build it to create any necessary libraries for my system.
However, every one of the sub projects within the Visual Studio solution, fail to open due to the error described above (w/ the 'GetType' function).
